# Traefik entrypoint redirect to scheme and port

Tags: traefik

I'm running traefik in docker-compose with `network_mode: host` to get an accurate remote_ip. My docker hosts ports 80 and 443 are occupied so traefik uses 5080 and 5443 web and websecure entry points. I've forwareded 5080/5443 to my routers 80/443 so `my.domain.me` routes to traefik. `https://my.domain.me` works correctly, but `http://my.domain.me` redirects to port 5443. How can I configure traefik to redirect to port 443?

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    # use host network for accurate remote_ip
    network_mode: host
    command: # CLI arguments
      - --providers.docker=true
      # ports 80 and 443 are used by another process.
      - --entryPoints.web.address=:5080
      - --entryPoints.websecure.address=:5443
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
```

Comment: This is probably because of HTTPS redirection (80 to 443) - can you confirm what happens if you don't use the last two lines?

Comment: I want https redirection, but I want to redirect to 443, not 80 to websecure's 5443 port

Comment: traefik will bind to any entrypoint and error when it is already occupied